# angular 2 - how to toggle classname

Tags: angular

I have this tab and panel component. it's working great now. However right now, wherever I click, only the first tab will have active class. I want to give the `active` class name to the clicked tab. And the tabs that are not clicked will not have `active` class name. How would you do it

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <div class="topicCreator">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item active" (click)="show('showDiscussion')">
                    <a class="nav-link active">Discussion</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" (click)="show('showEvent')">
                    <a class="nav-link">Event</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" (click)="show('showPoll')">
                    <a class="nav-link">Poll</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <CreateDiscussion *ngIf="showDiscussion"></CreateDiscussion>
            <CreatePoll *ngIf="showPoll"></CreatePoll>
            <CreateEvent *ngIf="showEvent"></CreateEvent>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./topicCreator.scss']
})
export class TopicCreatorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    public showDiscussion = true;
    public showPoll = false;
    public showEvent = false;

    show(tab){
        this.showDiscussion = false;
        this.showPoll = false;
        this.showEvent = false;

        if(tab == 'showDiscussion') {
            this.showDiscussion = true
        }
        if(tab == 'showPoll') {
            this.showPoll = true
        }
        if(tab == 'showEvent') {
            this.showEvent = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `ng-class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use class.active input as shown below

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" [class.active]="showDiscussion" (click)="show('showDiscussion')">
             <a class="nav-link">Discussion</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" (click)="show('showEvent')" [class.active]="showEvent">
             <a class="nav-link">Event</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" (click)="show('showPoll')" [class.active]="showPoll">
             <a class="nav-link">Poll</a>
        </li>
 </ul>
```